# Is it possible to use "That are" in any case?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number, relative-pronouns

I read few sentences in which I saw people use "That are" together, is it feasible to use like this or is there any possibility to use it?

I am bit of confused about it, can anybody please help me?

An example sentence, where I encountered this construction:

> Here is a list of adjectives and their synonyms **that are** commonly used to describe people.

Comment: You are probably dealing with *that* used as a relative pronoun, like *which* or *who*. Can you give us an example?

Comment: @StoneyB here in the below example you can see it

 Here is a list of adjectives and their synonyms that are commonly used to describe people.

Comment: Structurally the example is ambiguous (does "words commonly used to describe people" apply to "adjectives **and** their synonyms", or just "their synonyms"?). Semantically it's pretty strange too - after all, surely the *synonyms* of "adjectives" must be adjectives themselves, so where is the sense in identifying them separately?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Semantically I think it probably uses "and their synonyms" to describe the fact that the adjectives are grouped. I.e. Words commonly used to describe people include : thin (skinny, lanky, slender,slim), fat (thickset, stout, bulky, obese)...

Comment: @DRF: I know that, but designating one of each (semantic?) group as *the* "adjective" (with the others as mere synonyms) just seems weird to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, *that* is employed as a **relative** pronoun, not a **demonstrative** pronoun. It is equivalent to *which*:

> Here is a list of adjectives and their synonyms **{that / which}** are commonly used to describe people.

English relative pronouns do not inflect for number (singular or plural) as demonstrative pronouns do; they 'borrow' their number from their referents, the terms that they refer to. In this case, the referent of *that* is a little ambiguous—as FumbleFingers says, it may refer either to *synonyms* or to *adjectives and their synonyms*—but in any case the referent is plural, so *that* takes a plural verbform.